# Pandas: apply to all columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

For all cells in my dataframe, I just want to replace whitespace or empty (not NAN) with 0. Tried the below, but doesn't work.

Thank you

```
df1 = df1.all(apply(lambda x: 0 if x == ' ' or x=='' else x))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `replace`

```
df1 = df1.replace({' ':0,'':0})
```

or Change your function from apply to `mask`

```
df1 = df1.mask(df1.isin([' ', '']),0)
```